# Is there are way to compress Buffer data to a smaller size with NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, compression, buffer

I'm working on a Lambda function which fetches images from a Google drive and uploads it to S3 bucket.

The format of the data I'm working with is a Buffer and when I upload it to S3 bucket the size is 2.8mb. However I need to compress it to be under 2mb. I can't seem to find a suitable library which can handle this server side.

Any advice?

Comment: Have you tried [zlib](https://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html) of the NodeJS api?

Answer (score 1):

For compressing images and storing it, you may use `Jimp` which is an image processing library and provides all the facilities you're looking for.

For reference, you may go to this [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jimp)